# Can't get temperature from Openweathermap API

Tags: javascript, php, json, openweathermap

I am trying to get the temp variable out of the following JSON:

```
"weather": [
        {
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10n"
        },
],
"main": {
        "temp": 273.15,
        "pressure": 992,
        "humidity": 97,
        "temp_min": 273.15,
        "temp_max": 273.15
    },
```

I can get weather value using JavaScript:

```
 function print(xxx){
  var value = "";
    for(var i = 0;i < result.weather.length;i++){
    value += result.weather[i].main "<br/>";
    }
```

If i try to get temperature like this:

```
function print(xxx){
  var value = "";
    for(var i = 0;i < result.main.length;i++){
    value += result.main[i].temp "<br/>";
    }
```

I'm getting nothing. No errors or values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the type of data you're looking at. `weather` is an array. That's why you're using a `for` loop to go through each item in the array.

`main` is just an object. Nothing to iterate over. It doesn't even have a `length` property.

So to access `main`, forget the `for` loop altogether. Just access it directly.

```
value += result.main.temp + "<br />";
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually thought of this and even tried it, but apparently made a mistake since this is correct.